# Setting different permission classes for POST and GET while using djangorestframework's default router

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I was just watching some online tutorial on how to use Django Rest Framework to create a basic REST API using their default router. [Link to Docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)

but then because he used a model viewset he had to add permission_classes to them which means all different types of requests whether its post or get or others it'll all take the same permission.

I was wondering if there's a way to give them different permission_classes depending on the type of request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write your own permissions. 
Just create some python file. I named it permissions.py:

```
from rest_framework.generics import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission
from company.models import Company


class IsGetOrIsAuthenticated(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return True
        return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated


class IsGetOrIsCompanyOwner(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'GET' or 'OPTIONS':
            return True
        elif request.method == 'DELETE':
            company = get_object_or_404(Company, id=view.kwargs['pk'])
            return request.user.user_type == 'moder' or company.owner == request.user
        else:
            company = get_object_or_404(Company, id=view.kwargs['pk'])
            return company.owner == request.user or request.user.user_type == 'moder'


class IsModer(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.user_type == 'moder'
```

After that you can use them in views.py

```
from company.permissions import IsGetOrIsAuthenticated, IsGetOrIsCompanyOwner, IsModer

class ActiveCompanyShortView(ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsGetOrIsAuthenticated,)
```

you can read more [there](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#examples)

Comment: That works exactly how I wanted it but doesn't Django provide a isAuthenticatedOrReadOnly is it good enough to do the trick?

Comment: Yes it will works. But after use isAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, every one can do update. For example you have your own Company. If you will use isAuthenticatedOrReadOnly permission. Every user in system that authenticated can update or even delete your company. Writing your own permission can help you avoid this problem

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you need, one possible solution is to override the `get_permissions()` of `ViewSet`.

```
def get_permissions(self):
        """
        Instantiates and returns the list of permissions that this view requires.
        """
        if self.action == 'list':
            return [objects of permissions_u_need_in_list_view]

        elif self.action == 'create':
            return [objects of permissions_u_need_in_create_view]
```

This is what DRF provides the definition of `get_permissions()`.

```
def get_permissions(self):
        """
        Instantiates and returns the list of permissions that this view requires.
        """
        return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]
```